# How to use `dotnet ef migrations add XYZ` when there is a dependency on a COM reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, msbuild

I have a C# project with EF Core that depends on other projects, one of which depends on a COM reference.  It all worked well until now (I think an update to Visual Studio broke this).

Everything compiles in VisualStudio.  But on the command line, `dotnet build` returns this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2929,5): error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.
```

So, in short, I can't use EF Core Migrations anymore because it depends on `dotnet build`.  If I try to run `dotnet ef migrations add XYZ` I get this error:

```
Build started...
Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors.
```

My main program here (with the migrations) is a .NET 5.0, and the dependency that uses a COM reference is targeted to .NetCore3.1 (I could re-target to 5.0 if it helped).

So how can I either tell EF Migrations to use another MSBuild, or rollback to some previous tooling versions when this was not a problem, or make my COM reference a non-problem, or otherwise solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround.  Not sure it's the best way to go but it seems to work.

From [this blog](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/42848c63-4c19-418f-97a5-1b4d823f05f2/y):

1. Reference the COM dll and rebuild. Visual Studio will generate an interop dll. It will be named something like Interop.MyComDLL.dll. It is found in the build output directory.
2. Copy the generated Interop dll to somewhere in the application (I just used a /dlls folder at the root application level).
3. Remove the COM dll reference.
4. Add a direct reference (Dependencies > Add Reference... > Browse in Visual Studio) to the Interop dll

And may I add:

5. Mark the new dependency with the "copy local = yes" parameter.
6. [EDIT] And the "embed Interop Types = yes" parameter also.

Comment: rebuild the project .it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the next thing:

1. Build your solution via VS.
2. Provide `--no-build` argumetn to your migration command.

Unfortunatelly, the migrations command searches the output files in a bit different location. So, you have to copy those build output manually to the required location.

For example, my VS output location is `bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows`, but EF wants `bin\Debug\net7.0-windows`. So, I just copy everything from first path to the second, then run migration command.